# How to change values in OnTap Function when used in a for loop in Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

This is how my code looks like:

```
        List<Widgets> abc = [];

        for(int a = 0;a<5;a++)
        {
        abc.add(FlatButton(onTap:(){ print(a);},
                           child:Text("Hello - ${a}")
                           )
                 );
        }
```

When user clicks on "Hello - 2" Button, I want the output on console to be 2 but the output displayed is 5.

I have simplified the original problem in the form of this small programming question.I have checked a lot on internet but was unable to get any answer. Help me out please!!

Comment: It looks like you're not storing the a variable for each button. You're just converting it to a string to make the button name but when the button is pushed "a" still refers to your incrementing variable.

Comment: Yeah thats exactly what was happening the last time I checked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working just fine.

```dart
List<Widget> abc = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    for (int a = 0; a < 5; a++) {
      abc.add(FlatButton(
          onPressed: () {
            print(a);
          },
          child: Text("Hello - $a")));
    }
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: abc.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return abc[index];
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
```

And how can it return `5` when the max value of `a` is 4?

Comment: I don't know why and how this is working fine but last when I checked it was not storing the value of a. It was just taking the last value of a which was somehow 5. At that time the system may be taking garbage value (idk, it could be).

Comment: In the original problem, I was displaying the result in the form of a List and clicking on those result tiles, I wanted to animate to new Screen using Hero widget. So I made a function with a for loop and was using loop variable values as a tag for hero widget but every time the tag was taking the value '5' if the above-mentioned loop was used. I had no idea why this was happening.

Comment: So is this solution working for you ? or something else has to be addressed here? Update your question if you are having problems or accept the answer if this answer correctly addresses and solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the number in each button. Something like this. I have no idea how to use flutter so however you're supposed to do this, do it that way.

```
class customButton extends StatelessWidget {
int number = 0;
@override
customButton(int num){
  this.number = num;
}
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context){
return Text('button content' + number.toString());
}
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
List<customButton> buttons = new List();

for(int a = 0; a < 5; a++){
  buttons.add(new customButton(a));
}

return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text(widget.title),
  ),
  body: Center(
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: buttons
    ),
  )
);
}
}
```